# Google Calendar JavaScript API Throwing an Error

Tags: javascript, api, google-calendar-api

First things First here is a link to my web site:
[boba.dyndns-server.com/Test/index.html](http://boba.dyndns-server.com/Test/index.html).

After I click "Submit Courses", chnage the drop down from ignore to Specified, and click generate. It throws the error

```
Uncaught Error: An image of the same domain is required on this page for authenticated reads and all writes.
```

This error is thrown from line 215 in this [file](http://boba.dyndns-server.com/Test/scripts2.js)
Can anyone explain to me what is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have an image on your page.

[Source](http://groups.google.com/group/google-contacts-api/browse_thread/thread/4b1f97bd94b05efd)

```
"It means that your page needs to have at least one image (<img 
src="..." />) that's hosted off of your domain. It doesn't matter 
what, there just needs to be at least one image. 
It's a strange requirement, but that's part of the mechanism we use to 
bypass the same-origin policy. 
-- 
Trevor Johns 
"
```